# Allow only specific users to login using everyauth

Tags: node.js, express, everyauth

I have an expressjs app with everyauth setup.

Everyauth is working fine. Now, I want everyauth to allow users to login into the app whose email id matches a regular expression.

Say I want people to login whose email starts with the letter "foo" (suppose, footest@gmail.com) or is of a specific domain like adeptocorp.com (suppose node@adeptocorp.com)

Kindly provide me some solution to solve this situation

Comment: > Kindly provide me some solution to solve this situation |||| You should probably consider telling us what you've tried and why/how it's failed. Just asking for a solution will get you nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use password authentication (which I presume cause otherwise you don't have to care about e-mail addresses) then you can use the `validateRegistration` function.

For others, write a piece of connect middleware like:

```
function checkEmail(regex){
  return function (req, res, next) {
      // get everyauth.user via the everyauth helper
      if (!everyauth.user.email.test(regex)) {
          res.writeHead(403);
          res.end("e-mail address not allowed");
      }
      else { next(); }
  }
};
```

And use it right after the `everyauth` use like:

```
connect // or express
...
.use(checkEmail)
```